# Install XBMC inside Ubuntu?

Tags: xbmc

Is it possible to install XBMC inside Ubuntu without changing the whole system?

I would like to use the system for my Videos but I also need my Ubuntu unity desktop.

Comment: Just be aware that XBMC is going to be changing to a new product name in the near future to become "Kodi". Currently in beta.

Comment: I thought if I install with apt I would change the whole system (like with `atp-get install kubunut-desktop`)?

Comment: No, it will install as a stand-alone app. Using the answer provided by Henry below, you will get the latest XBMC stable build. This is how I have it installed on my system as well as my HTPC box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To install XBMC you can run the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:team-xbmc/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install xbmc
```